# Check List has only one non null element and retrieve it using Java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

How to check whether the list has only one non-null element and if so retrieve the same using java 8 or Streams?

One of my method return list of objects which needs to check whether the returned list contains only one non null object, If so it creates a map as defined below else, needs to log an error as below.

```
`public void myMethod() {
    List<MyClass> tst = getAll();
    if(!tst.isEmpty() ) {
      if( tst.size() == 1) {
       if(tst.get(0)!= null) {
          MyClass class1 = tst.get(0);
          Map<Integer,MyClass> m = 
             Stream.of(class1).collect(Collectors.toMap(MyClass:: getId, 
                 Function.identity()));
          }
        }
      else {
        LOGGER.error("Multiple object found - {} object", tst.size());
      }
    }`
```

I'm looking for a way to write in a clean and standard format as I have three If conditions

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Perhaps, the same way you'd do it in any other Java version.

Comment: Why use `Stream`'s for this? Why not just a simple size check, a `get()` and a `null` check?

Comment: @GBlodgett if you want to write an enterprise-grade, cloud-based BlockChain microservice, you have to use streams.

Comment: What do you mean "retrieve the same"?

Comment: `if(tst.size() == 1 && tst.get(0) != null) return Collections.singletonMap(tst.get(0).getId(), tst.get(0));` The test for “not empty” is redundant, as a list of size one is not empty and using the Stream API has no benefit here.

Comment: Added additional information

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do the trick but it's not using streams. If you really need to use streams say so and I'll give it a try with it :)

```
int notNullCount = 0;
Object myNotNullElement;
for (Object element : myArray){
    if (notNullCount > 1){
        //Throw exception or do whaterver you need to do to signal this
        break;
    }

    if (element != null){
        myNotNullElement = element;
        notNullCount++;
    }
}
```